# Power Consumption of an Application

Tags: linux

Is there any way to find out the power consumed by an application. Like if i have some ten user apps running on my laptop and would like to know how much power each application is consuming in Linux environment?

Comment: *Power*? You mean, in *watts*?

Comment: To those voting to close...the on- or off-topicness of this depends on just *why* nikhil wants to know.

Answer (score 4):

The [PowerTop](http://www.linuxpowertop.org/index.php) tool might have something for you. Lookup the section "Power usage". If the tool itself is not what you want, you can research, where the tool retrieves its information and evaluate them in the way you want.

Answer (score 2):

That's an interesting question and does not have a easy answer that I've heard of.

Presuming that you have a way of metering the minute to minute consumption of the machine. You can get a crude approximation by examining the amount of CPU time used. Either by watching things in `top`, or by examining the output of `time (1)`. Compare the machine's total power consumption in various states of idleness and load to the amount of work done by each process---with enough statistics you should have a solvable system...possibly even a over-constrained one that calls for some kind of best-fit solution.

---

The only way that occurs to me to do it to high precision would be to use

1. Instrumented virtual machine that accumulated statistics on what parts of the CPU were activated. (Do such things exist at this time?!?)
2. The manufacturers documentation for the chip-n-board you are running on to total up the power implied.

which would be a horribly complicated mess.

Sorting out which bits were needed just to provide the environment and which could be unambiguously attributed to the program won't be easy.

---

I have to ask...why?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there's really a "good way" to do this. But here's a suggestion for a generic approach that would work regardless of operating system: Remove the battery from your laptop, and hook up its power adapter to a high-precision current meter. Note the draw when no "normal" applications are running. Then run each application on its own and note the differences in current draw.